# Is "after" in this context solely a local colloquialism?

Tags: american-english, british-english, colloquialisms

There are a number of turns of phrase that I have to avoid as an English person speaking to an American audience. Would it be possible for someone to clarify whether this colloquialism is American-friendly:

> Q: Can I buy four candles?
>
> A: Is this what you're **after**?

I'd speculate that this is an abbreviation of "chasing after", which in itself is a colloquialism for "looking for".

Does this phrase cross the Atlantic? Or even make sense outside of the West Country?

Comment: I'm a little curious...what "turns of phrase" do you have to avoid with an American audience? And why do you feel you have to avoid them?

Comment: trousers (pants), pants (underpants), pants (not very good), welly (rubber boot), p*ssed (drunk), 13/1/12 (1/13/12), colour (color), taking the mick out of (making fun of), cheers (thanks), boot (trunk), fag (cigarette), drizzle (half-arsed rain), half-arsed (not very well implemented)...

Comment: To answer your second question: To improve ease of understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is common in the United States as well. It's colloquial but not improper, and certainly would be understood.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have said it was a feature of a certain social dialect. In shops where I live (not West Country), you're quite likely to hear *What was you after?* However, the OED has an entry for *to be after* in the sense of 'To be trying to get or achieve (something)' with no usage comment.

Comment: Is you saying I talks common? ;)

Comment: @StuartPegg: Not at all. I don't make that kind of judgement in discussing language.